# Cannot get any of my JS functions used by controls to work when the JS is moved to an external file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some controls on a webform which are using JS to do certain things like call a function to change a textbox and a calendar control client side. This works great but i wanted to move all my JS to an external file. I have been searching everywhere but i cannot find what i am looking for.

Lets say I have a js function that a control and sets a date to it

```
    function DateChanged(sender, args)
    {
        $find("calExTo").set_startDate(sender._selectedDate);
        $find("calExTo").set_selectedDate(sender._selectedDate);
    }
```

This works in a script tag in the webform but I want to move it to a seperate JS file, so I can keep all my js functions in one place.

I add the file to the head 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsFile.js"></script>

but now i keep getting undefined DateChanged function, please can someone help me so i understand what is going on here. As you can tell I am a novice at JS.

Comment: Is `js/jsFile.js` definitely accessable by the page? The browser's inspector should show the full src it's attempting to load, and if it fails.

Comment: yep as i have a few functions in there but these are directly being called by c# in the code behind. I did that using the register startup script

Comment: Bit confused. Both back-end and clientside is accessing this js script at the same time?

Comment: well not at the same time, but yes. I have functions which I want to execute in code and i have some which controls on the webform rely on

Comment: I see. You'll need to keep those in separate files. In fact the back-end ones probably shouldn't really be publically accessible at all as it can expose application logic.

Comment: but how would that make a difference, sure i will split back end and front end up. But even then i will still have the same issue

Comment: I'm sorry it's not super clear what's going on. `js/jsFile.js` contains functions meant for the front-end client AND the back end server? If that's the case it may well be the front end is failing to parse them.

Comment: Sorry but that makes me more confused, as if it was failing then non of my functions would work when I call them from the backend. Isn't this meant to be like an includes. So they are already loaded and when you needed them you just call them. Not only that but i also have a drag and drop feature which works in the file.

Comment: Going back to the first comment, is `js/jsFile.js` definitely loaded? Can you see it loaded the browser's dev tools, network tab? If no or not sure try adding a slash at the start - `/js/jsFile.js`. Otherwise we should see the page markup with the js and at least one of the controls that's trying to call a function. Also the sentence in your question that starts "Lets say I have a js function..." is incomplete; there are some words missing.

Comment: yes the JS is loaded in the browser dev tools, i thought my response actually dealt with that. Anyway i am unsure as to what you mean my sentence is incomplete? and what has that got to do with the issue anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after restarting the computer I no longer have a problem, i think this must have been a caching issue. Although the amount of times i tried refreshing the browser still not take affect. I closed the computer for the night and came back to it the next morning and it was working.